# При добавлении и редактировании файлов темы(не активной) Wordpress в докер из VS Code по ssh падает база данных

Tags: wordpress, docker, ssh, visual-studio-code

Есть VPS сервер на котором запущен докер. В разных контейнерах Nginx, Wordpress, MySql. Подключился к разделу `var/lib/docker/volumes/wordpress` докер контейнера Wordpress из VS Code с помощью  Remote SSH. Добавил папку в темы. Тема даже не активна, но постоянно спустя некоторое время работы в VS Code с фалами темы отключается соединение в VS Code, на сайт не заходит, ошибка базы данных, проверяю контейнер MySql - перезапущен.

Логи:

```
2021-03-14 19:51:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.
2021-03-14 19:51:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-03-14 19:51:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.
2021-03-14T19:51:13.730248Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-03-14T19:51:13.734256Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.33) starting as process 1 ...
2021-03-14T19:51:13.742962Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-03-14T19:51:13.743231Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-03-14T19:51:13.743346Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-14T19:51:13.743436Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-03-14T19:51:13.743532Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-14T19:51:13.743604Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-03-14T19:51:13.748323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-14T19:51:13.750896Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-03-14T19:51:13.760827Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-03-14T19:51:13.761452Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2021-03-14T19:51:13.761605Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2021-03-14T19:51:13.761688Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-03-14T19:51:13.761783Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-03-14T19:51:13.761869Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-03-14T19:51:13.761944Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-03-14T19:51:13.762014Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-03-14T19:51:13.762107Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-03-14T19:51:13.762495Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2021-03-14T19:51:13.763931Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Непонятная ситуация, так быть не должно. Приложите логи проблемных контейнеров `docker logs -f --tail 100 имя-контейнера` (mysql, wordpress). Если логов мускул не создает, приложите Dockerfile чтобы были понятны настройки. Если используете docker-compose, то можно посмотреть сразу все `docker-compose logs -f --tail 100`. И еще странный этот путь `/var/lib/docker/volumes/wordpress` - обычно чтобы работать с сорцами, монтируется том в локальную папку, и с ней уже работают.

Comment: @Total Pusher там уже в сотню не поместится. Последняя ошибка вообще была "segmentation fault", пришлось перезагружать. Я решил что проблема в правах доступа, т. к. я был тогда под рутом. Создал пользователя, примонтировал папку wordpress к внешней, добавил пользователя в группу `www-data`, как у всех файлов wordpress, и дал этой группе права на запись. Уже часа полтора полет нормальный. Пока посмотрю, надеюсь проблема была в руте и VS Code. А может действительно я не в те папки лез. Спасибо.

Comment: Нет. Проблема доступов не может иметь такие катастрофические последствия. Но вот работа в `/var/lib/docker/volumes/wordpress` и `segmentation fault` вполне может быть. Я до сих не понимаю как можно работать с этим каталогом. Там лежат тома докера. Вы, что напрямую в эти тома лазили, в бинарные файлы? Но как ...

Comment: @Total Pusher  под рутом пускает в эти папки) Опять все упало, правда в этот раз тема была активна, и с базой данных все вроде норм.. Я работал в конструкторе WP в плагине Unyson и хотел добавить папку в VS Code. В логах много личных данных, не хотелось бы выкладывать в публичный доступ. Отфильтровал только ошибки. Там сейчас только одна `wordpress_1          | 2021-03-13T20:09:31.794569733Z [Sat Mar 13 20:09:27.650324 2021] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process` Может просто ОЗУ мало?

Comment: @Total Pusher  опять DB упала. Добавил логи. Это все-таки память?

Comment: Мало памяти. Напишите сколько у вас (`free -m`). Вот тут советуют уменьшить аппетиты мускула https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167454/error-innodb-mmap137428992-bytes-failed-errno-12

Comment: @Total Pusher  ок, про мускул гляну. Спасибо. Я вчера уже начал копать в сторону памяти и в ответе прикрепил отчет по ОЗУ. Буду еще думать как умерить аппетит VS Code.

Comment: Мне не понятно, почему VS Code жрет память на сервере. Вы подключаетесь по SSH, а соединение не может отжирать 678 - 298 = 380 метров. Я с VS Code не работаю. Нужно понять почему происходит потребление памяти. Может он запускает что-то вроде `npm run watch`? Посмотрите top/htop или `ps aux` что там за процессы крутятся до и после - вне контейнера. И я до сих пор не понял, зачем вам каталог `/var/lib/docker/volumes/wordpress` сдался? Что вы с ним делаете? Там лежат волюмы в специальном формате, не знаю зачем он вам понадобился. PS. Можно поднять через вагрант/виртуалбокс свой сервак дома.

Comment: @Total Pusher  я уже перемонтировал коталог wordpress во внешнюю директорию. Проверил `ps aux`. Она(VS Code) запускает какие-то свои процессы из `/home/*username*/.vscode-server/bin/`. Я так понимаю, когда устанавливаешь плагин, используя ssh, он ставится на сервер. Мне кажется это плагины жрут память. P. S. да, я уже тоже подумал работать на компе, а потом залить на сервер. Не хотел лишнюю работу делать, просто отключил индексацию в поисковиках и пилю тему сразу на проде) Пока перезагружаю VS Code периодически)

Comment: Я думаю, процесс прибивает OOM Killer. Эта такая штука, которая грохает процессы, когда заканчивается память. У нее есть [свой алгоритм](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) выбора "жертвы". И делает это не в пользу мускуля. Посмотрите `sudo grep -i killed /var/log/syslog` (или `/var/log/messages`) после завершения мускуля. Если там будет подобное `Killed process 2138, UID 27, (mysqld)`, то это оно. Как с этим справиться можно посмотреть [тут](https://lwn.net/Articles/317814/)

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел проблему.

Спустя время работы в VS Code вот что происходит с ОЗУ, при том что MySql уже не запускается.

```
            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         985M        678M         70M         36M        236M        141M
Swap:          0B          0B          0B
```

Закрываю VS Code

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           985M        298M        440M         36M        246M        522M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```